# Sum across sheets of (if cell x equals get cell y)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

Hello there im struggling for how to eplain this in a sentence and thus have been all over the web and thot id best just ask someone.

So we have a sales file with daily sales sheets. what im looking for is a formula that will get all sales for specific salesman from each day and total them. so it basically has to get the data from Cell C:% if cell I:% = David, for each table on all sheets and give me a total of this so i can say form a table

Now the sheet already uses macros for data entry so i can use macros, i would ofc prefer a formula to complete this is anyone knows of any?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sumif like this:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!I:I,"David",Sheet1!C:C)+SUMIF(Sheet2!I:I,"David",Sheet2!C:C)+...
```

for each sheets, but I would write simple UDF:

```
Function SumIF_AllSheets(criteriaRng As Range, criteria, sumRng As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        SumIF_AllSheets = SumIF_AllSheets + WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Range(criteriaRng.Address), criteria, ws.Range(sumRng.Address))
    Next
End Function
```

and call it like this: `SumIF_AllSheets(I:I,"David",C:C)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **sheetlist** is a named range listing all the other sheet names you can use this formula in cell B2 of your summary sheet copied down, where A2 down lists salespeople's names

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&sheetlist&"'!I:I"),A2,INDIRECT("'"&sheetlist&"'!C:C")))`

Comment: Ok sorry so how do i specify %sheetlist% becuase i have other sheets on here that it shouldnt check, such as data entry form sheet etc. becuase its currently giving me an error when i copy baste in to a table with a2down being salesmans names and the b2down with your formula

Comment: The simplest way is to list all sheet names somewhere on your summary sheet, one name per cell - then select the list, right-click and use "Define Name"